# Is it possible to replace duplicates of a character with one character using tr

Tags: linux, text-processing, replace, tr

I'm trying to take all occurrences of # and if they are consecutive replace them with just one #.

e.g.

```
 ab ### cde fghi## jklm
```

would become:

```
ab # cde, fghi# jklm
```

My initial goal was to replace all consecutive digits with # so; 120 -> # and 3->#. However I found that 120->###. So now I'm left with this new problem.

Answer (score 20):

Using `tr -s`:

```
$ echo 'ab ### cde fghi## jklm' | tr -s '#'
ab # cde fghi# jklm
```

---

> `-s`      Squeeze multiple occurrences of the characters listed in the last operand (either string1 or string2) in the input into a single instance of the character.
>                    This occurs after all deletion and translation is completed.

---

Your original problem could have been solved with:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+/#/g'
```

Or POSIXly:

```
sed 's/[[:digit:]]\{1,\}/#/g'
```

Or:

```
tr -s '[:digit:]' '[#*]'
```